# [EMBED_DESCRIPTION]: MessageEmbed description must be a string

Tags: javascript

This is my code and im getting this error: RangeError [EMBED_DESCRIPTION]: MessageEmbed description must be a string can can someone help me please? i want to make leaderboard

````
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Database = require("@replit/database");
const db = new Database();

module.exports = {
  name: "Leaderboard",
  aliases: ['leader', 'leaderboard', 'топ', 'Топ'],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const collection = new Collection();

    await Promise.all(
      message.guild.members.cache.map(async (member) => {
        const id = member.id;
        const bal = await db.get(`balance_${id}`);

        console.log(`${member.user.tag} -> ${bal}`);
        return bal !== 0
          ? collection.set(id, {
              id,
              bal,
            })
          : null;
      })
    );

    const data = collection.sort((a, b) => b.bal - a.bal).first(10);

    message.channel.send(
      new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Leaderboard in ${message.guild.name}`)
        .setDescription(
          data.map((v, i) => {
            return `${i + 1}) ${client.users.cache.get(v.id).tag} => **${v.bal} coins**`;
          })
        )
    );
  },
};```
````

Comment: Your _data.map_ in _setDescription_ is obviously not returning a string, check with a _console.log_ including a _typeof()_ and tell us what the output is.

Answer (score 0):

In `setDescription` you're calling `data.map(...)` which returns an array. You can use `Array.prototype.join` to create a string from the array elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

`data.map(...).join('\n')`

If your array looked like this `['abc', 'def', 'ghi']` then the output of the `join` would be a string that looks like this:

```
abc
def
ghi
```